# Program Permissions

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, permissions, user-accounts

I am creating an application in vb.net that accesses a database on a drive that other students do not have access to. The program will not run correctly if it is run under one of these students accounts. How can I make it so the program will access the db under any account?

Comment: What type of database? if its SQL instead of using Windows Integrated use SQL Server Authentication. Please re-tag your question with the flavor of database, thanks..

Comment: using the connection strings you should be able to do that.

Comment: It is a Microsoft Access database.

Comment: This is my current connection string...."Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & fileName.....what would I have to change?

Comment: Well they need access to that drive, or a copy of the mdb on a drive they do have access to. Only other option would be to have the code run as an other user with permission (not recommended, or to go client server. Ie you wriet a service that can access teh db, and then the app you have now talks to that. Fair bit of work and learning that though.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson I'd put that comment of yours an answer mate.

Answer (score 1):

Well they need access to that drive, or a copy of the mdb on a drive they do have access to. Only other option would be to have the code run as an other user with permission (not recommended), or to go client server. I.e. you write a service that can access the db, and then the app you have now talks to that. Fair bit of work and learning that though.

Answer (score 0):

To give other students the ability to connect to your Access Databases you'll need to set File Permissions Read/Write or Full control.

Comment: Not just the file, the whole folder in which the mdb resides. Access creates a lock file (.ldb) and if all users do not have permissions on the lock file, the first user in will lock everyone else out. Delete permissions can be a good idea as well.