# Parallel Filter Algorithm in C#

Tags: c#, filter, parallel-processing

I am looking for an implementation of a [parallel filter algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filter_%28higher-order_function%29) in C#.

Comment: Add more information of your problem. Give an example of what you are trying to accomplish. Add in some code that does the procedure in a non parallel manner to help us understand the actual need.

Comment: In general, the answer is probably .AsParallel().Where(... or some other LINQ ex method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
myCollection.AsParallel().Where(...);
```

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460714.aspx

Comment: Thats the answer @YoryeNathan put as a comment 4 minutes before you?

Comment: Well, it *is* the answer, and since Yorye didn't post it as an answer I did.

Comment: IMHO its better SO etiquette to tell someone their comment is answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9880994/program-permissions#comment12602770_9880994 We can disagree on this but @YoryeNathan does contribute to the site... 0/80 QA rate. ps its not the answer until it has a green tick under it;)

Comment: Removed "TIP: Google is your friend". That didn't add anything to your answer.

Answer (score 2):

You're probably looking for [`ParallelEnumerable.AsParallel Method`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.parallelenumerable.asparallel.aspx):

```
var data = Enumerable.Range(1, 100000000).Select(i => i);
var even = data.AsParallel().Where(i => i % 2 == 0);
```

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163329.aspx (not up-to-date)

  - [List of changes since above article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2007/11/29/6558508.aspx)
- [Overview of videos/articles according this topic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/concurrency/ee851578.aspx)
- [PDF: When To Use ParallelForEach Or PLINQ](http://download.microsoft.com/download/B/C/F/BCFD4868-1354-45E3-B71B-B851CD78733D/WhenToUseParallelForEachOrPLINQ.pdf)
- [When PLINQ will speedup performance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997399.aspx)

**Edit**: The above example is **not** a good candidate for PLINQ since the mudulo operation is not enough work and the overhead of parallelization will offset most or all of the speedup.

I've copied the links from [my own question on the same subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7582591/how-to-plinq-an-existing-linq-query-with-joins), they are all worth reading.